# matching form input to mysql database value

Tags: php, mysql, preg-match

I have a mysql database with a set of predefined telephone numbers, that looks like this.

> CREATE TABLE `brukerTabell` (
>     `bruID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>     `fornavn` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
>     `etternavn` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
>     `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
>     `telefon`
>   set('98979695','97969594','90807090','90908080','40908070','45674849','46573823','45343456') NOT NULL,
>     `fdag` date NOT NULL,
>     PRIMARY KEY (`bruID`)
>   ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

Now I want the telefonnumber that is filled out in my html form to only validate if it matches with one of these numbers. Till now i have this code, but that only validates the input as a number

```
$telefon = $_POST['telefon'];
$telefonregex = '[0-9]{8}';
if (!preg_match($telefonregex, $telefon)) {
    echo 'Invalid number';
}
```

Any way to pull the numbers out of the mysql database with a variabel in my php document and see if there is a match? Or any other solution to check for a match? So I dont have to write ever number in the preg_match.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here... Your posted phone numbers are validated with regex (presume they are then inserted into the database?) - are you asking if you can validate all numbers already in the database without using PHP (e.g. using MySQL's regex: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211395/list-enum-values-in-dropdown-php-mysql

Comment: @pregmatch Dont think thats what he wants. He actually wants somebody to write the PHP code to check the entered number exists on his table. Questioner, its simple enough, but not the ethos of this site.  Try something and if it does not work, ask for assistance, not free consultancy.

Comment: First of all, he is a she, and I dont want someone to write the code. I am asking if there is any way to pull the numbers out of the database with out writing them all, and if the "set" function in the database is the correct way to predefine the values. Is there a SELECT X from X syntax that i perhaps can use. I havent written the code because I dont have a clue if there is such a thing

Answer (score 0):

No, that's a trade off sets, you'll have to insert the value, and then check if it is well inserted to rollback if it is not, easy way using a select concat_ws on the telefon field and check if the length of that string is the same as the one you entered.